Vapi Assistant can not read Webhook response
I was trying to integrate Vapi with make.com, In my scenario I was providing a three digit number to the assistant, and the assistant would say the name from the database for the corresponding number. The number and name I stored in a google sheet.
Now, I can send the name to tha vapi through webhook response. Make.com log suggests that name would have been sent to vapi, as the Body contains the name.
In Vapi I can find the name in the webhook response as well. But the assistant can not read or find the response. What should I do?
My prompt is

You will ask the number from the caller. Number will be of three digit
You may retrieve data about a customer's name using the Number tools with the parameter 'Number', which will contain the user's number to verify their identity before fetching their Name.
The functions may return with a message specifying the name or an error message saying the number given by the customer was invalid and does not exist. In the case that the number is not valid and does not exist you may ask them for their number again to try the request again if they would like.
After the customer has no questions, kindly thank them for their call and hang up.

In make.com I used
Webhook (custom webhook)
Gsheet (Search rows)
Router
Webhook (response) for valid number
Webhook (response) for invalid number
I send the name in the Body of the Webhook response as plain text. Only mention the Gsheet column value.
In vapi tools I used two parameters, Number and Name with Number being a required one.
help me in the proceedings to read the output from the webhook response in vapi assistant.
Asking the assistant with a valid number to return the name, but it returns no information is there

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
